# Python Bokeh define preselected ones in legend.click_policy = 'hide' or 'mute'

Tags: python, bokeh

in [this example](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html)

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=250, x_axis_type="datetime")
p.title.text = 'Click on legend entries to hide the corresponding lines'

for data, name, color in zip([AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG], ["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"], Spectral4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    p.line(df['date'], df['close'], line_width=2, color=color, alpha=0.8, legend=name)

p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy="hide"

output_file("interactive_legend.html", title="interactive_legend.py example")

show(p)
```

all lines are shown by default. Is there a way to hide e.g. all lines but "IBM" when the graph is created? What is the flag to address the status "hidden" or "not hidden"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `renderer.visible = False` to hide some glyphs

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG

p = figure(plot_width = 800, plot_height = 250, x_axis_type = "datetime", title = 'Glyphs hidden by default')

lines = {}
for data, name, color in zip([AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG], ["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"], Spectral4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    lines[name] = p.line(df['date'], df['close'], line_width = 2, color = color, alpha = 0.8, legend = name)
    lines[name].visible = True if name == "IBM" else False

p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy = "hide"

show(p)
```

Comment: Great, thx! It didnt work for me in the beginning as I used click_policy = mute. There the renderer to use is "muted", just for completeness. But otherwise exactely what I was searching for.

Comment: you can use "mute" but then you need to specifiy a parameter like "muted_alpha=0.35" in p.line()

Comment: I found a bug of this method for "muted" case. If ``click_policy='mute'``, then using ``lines[name].visible = False`` would make the line disappear. I used ``line[name].muted = True`` and the result is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

here is a sample using checkbox..(for fun):

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import row

code = """
    if (0 in checkbox.active) {
        l0.visible = true
    } else {
        l0.visible = false
    }
    if (1 in checkbox.active) {
        l1.visible = true
    } else {
        l1.visible = false
    }
    if (2 in checkbox.active) {
        l2.visible = true
    } else {
        l2.visible = false
    }
    if (3 in checkbox.active) {
        l3.visible = true
    } else {
        l3.visible = false
    }        
"""

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=250, x_axis_type="datetime")
p.title.text = 'Click on legend entries to hide the corresponding lines'

l=[]
for data, name, color in zip([AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG], ["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"], Spectral4 ):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    l.append( p.line(df['date'], df['close'], line_width=2, color=color, alpha=0.8, legend=name))


p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy = "hide"

output_file("interactive_legend.html", title="interactive_legend.py example")

callback = CustomJS(code=code, args={})
checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"], active=[0, 1, 2, 3], callback=callback, width=100)
callback.args = dict(l0=l[0], l1=l[1], l2=l[2], l3=l[3],  checkbox=checkbox)

layout = row(checkbox, p)
show(layout)
```

[image]